# When does keycloak delete expired sessions?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I noticed that sessions that pass the **SSO session idle** and **SSO session max** aren't immediately deleted. They seem to be invalidated and therefor useless, but they are not getting immediately removed. I can view them in the sessions tab of the admin console.

Since I can't find an explanation for this, or how this mechanism works internally (didn't look into the code), I was wondering, if anyone could elaborate on what is going on? Is everything working as it should?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the Keycloak Admin UI is not reactive, which means that the status of the session is not immediately reflect on the UI.

Comment: Hm, I'm not quite sure about this, since creating sessions is instantly reflected. Same applies to logging out.

Comment: What do you mean with "immediately deleted"? How long does it takes? 30 sec / 5 min / 2 days?

Comment: I didn't benchmark it. But when I log in and immediately update the UI panel, the session will be shown. Same is true for logging out. It will be immediately (as immediate as switching to the browser and refreshing the website can be) reflected.

This is not the same for a session expiring (and getting invalidated). I can see the session after minutes in the admin panel. Though it gets deleted after some time (not sure how long exactly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keycloak relies heavily on Infinispan for caching. Many types of entities have dedicated caches configured directly to them, and sessions are not excluded.

When starting Keycloak, you specifiy a configuration file/operation mode ( via the `-c` parameter). For example, when I run my keycloak via docker I get the following command line:

```sh
java -D[Standalone] -server -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true --add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.misc=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED -Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/log/server.log -Dlogging.configuration=file:/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/logging.properties -jar /opt/jboss/keycloak/jboss-modules.jar -mp /opt/jboss/keycloak/modules org.jboss.as.standalone -Djboss.home.dir=/opt/jboss/keycloak -Djboss.server.base.dir=/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone -Djboss.bind.address=172.19.0.3 -Djboss.bind.address.private=172.19.0.3 -c=standalone-ha.xml -Dkeycloak.profile.feature.token_exchange=enabled -Dkeycloak.profile.feature.admin_fine_grained_authz=enabled
```

you can see `-D[Standalone]` (for the operation mode) and `-c=standalone-ha.xml`, which points to the configuration XML file.

In it, you can see a section in the likes of:

```xml
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:11.0">
        <cache-container name="keycloak" module="org.keycloak.keycloak-model-infinispan">
            <local-cache name="realms">
                <heap-memory size="10000"/>
            </local-cache>
            <local-cache name="users">
                <heap-memory size="10000"/>                 
            </local-cache>
            <local-cache name="sessions"/>
            <local-cache name="authenticationSessions"/>
            <local-cache name="offlineSessions"/>
            <local-cache name="clientSessions"/>
            <local-cache name="offlineClientSessions"/>
            <local-cache name="loginFailures"/>
            <local-cache name="work"/>
            <local-cache name="authorization">
                <heap-memory size="10000"/>
            </local-cache>
            <local-cache name="keys">
                <heap-memory size="1000"/>
                <expiration max-idle="3600000"/>
            </local-cache>
            <local-cache name="actionTokens">
                <heap-memory size="-1"/>
                <expiration interval="300000" max-idle="-1"/>
            </local-cache>
        </cache-container>
        ...
        ...
        ...
    </subsystem>
```

You can try and tweak the various session caches `expiration`/`lifespan` attributes.

Have a look at [Cache-Configuration](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/#cache-configuration) section of the manual, and also on the xmlns [infinispan-config specification](https://docs.jboss.org/infinispan/11.0/configdocs/infinispan-config-11.0.html)

Comment: I have checked the cache-configuration documentation. It shows how to set things up. Though it doesn't mention the difference in behavior when the user logs out vs when the session expires.

Comment: Just a thought - write operations (actively logout) invalidate caches, while expiring items (what happens when a session expires) are simply purged during next  scan/refresh/reaping interval. That is a very standard caching behavior.

Comment: That is what I assumed. I'm not very knowledgeable in this field. Thanks for the input.

Just for someone reading this in the future: Even the next token request won't delete the session. The response will be "access denied".